# Problema na hora de excluir o produto do carrinho na linguagem php

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, framework

Estou com problema na hora de excluir o produto do carrinho, quando excluo um produto do meio ou o primeiro produto acaba excluído 2 ou mais, porém se eu começo a excluir o produto de baixo para cima ele vai normalmente e o site não dá problema. Creio que o problema está com problema de organização do vetor ao ser excluído o produto deixando ele vazio.

**Imagem de como está o vetor após ser feito uma exclusão fora da ordem:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oixYk.png)

**Código responsável por excluir o arquivo:**

```
`<?php
    session_start();
    $produto = $_GET["produto"];

    unset($_SESSION["produto"][$produto]);
    unset($_SESSION["valor"][$produto]);
    
    //fazer um for para percorre os espaços vazios apagar essas posições que estão vazias

    header("location: carrinho2.php");

?>`
```

**Código de exibição do carrinho:**

`<

```
?php
 session_start();

 $cont=0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['produto']) && isset($_SESSION["valor"])){
      for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['produto']); $i++){
        if(isset ($_SESSION['produto'][$i]) && isset($_SESSION["valor"][$i])){

        ?>
          <div style="text-align: center; font-family: time news roman; border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 5px; width: 600px; padding: 30px; margin-left: 395px; ">
            <h5><?php echo $_SESSION['produto'][$i]?></h5>
            <h5><?php echo "R$".$_SESSION["valor"][$i]?></h5>

        <?php
      
      ?>
            <a href="apagar.php?produto=<?php echo $i;?>"><button style="background:blue darken-2">Excluir</button></a>
          </div><br>

         <?php
      }
        if(isset($_SESSION["valor"][$i])){
         $cont += $_SESSION["valor"][$i];
        }
      }
      ?>
      <div style="text-align: center; font-family: time news roman; border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 5px; width: 600px; padding: 30px; margin-left: 395px;">
      <h4>Valor total do carrinho:<?php echo $cont ?></h4>
      </div>
<?php
 }
 
?>`
```

**pequena parte do código responsável por mandar o produto para o carrinho:**

```
`else if($pagina == "blusas"){
            $blusas = array("imagens/floralbordada.JPG","imagens/blusinhalistrada.webp","imagens/blusapreta.JPG");
            $descricao = array("Blusa floral bordada.", "Costas Nuas Listrado Boho Blusa.", "Blusas Colarinho Entalhado Manga Bufante.");
            $valor = array(79.90, 89.90, 99.90);
            echo '<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap;">';
            echo '<div style="text-align: center;">
                      <img src="'.$blusas[0].'" style="width: 250px; margin-right: 20px; height:261px">
                      <p>'.$descricao[0].'</p>
                      <p>R$'.$valor[0].'</p>
                      <a href="carrinho.php?descricao='.$descricao[0].'&valor='.$valor[0].'" class="btn blue darken-2">Comprar</a>
                  </div>';
            echo '<div style="text-align: center;">
                      <img src="'.$blusas[1].'" style="width: 248px; margin-right: 20px; height:264px">
                      <p>'.$descricao[1].'</p>
                      <p>R$'.$valor[1].'</p>
```

type here

```
                      <a href="carrinho.php?descricao='.$descricao[1].'&valor='.$valor[1].'" class="btn blue darken-2">Comprar</a>
                  </div>';
            echo '<div style="text-align: center;">
                      <img src="'.$blusas[2].'" style="width: 250px; margin-right: 20px;">
                      <p>'.$descricao[2].'</p>
                      <p>R$'.$valor[2].'</p>
                      <a href="carrinho.php?descricao='.$descricao[2].'&valor='.$valor[2].'"class="btn blue darken-2">Comprar</a>
                  </div>';
            echo '</div>';
        } `
```

**código que recebemos o produto:**

```
`<?php 
  session_start();
    $descricao = $_GET['descricao'];
    $valor = $_GET["valor"];

    
    $_SESSION['produto'][] = $descricao;
    $_SESSION["valor"][] = (float)$valor;

  header("location: carrinho2.php");

?>
```

Eu espera que fosse excluído um produto um por vez independente da ordem dele, porém não é isso que aconteceu, ao clicar em excluir um produto que está no meio ou o primeiro produto, o vetor começa a bagunçar, não começa mais em 0, não imprime o produto mesmo recebendo ele no vetor, e por fim, ao ser excluído um produto do meio ou o primeiro produto ele exclui mais de 2

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/585149/70)  e instruções já foram dadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar duplicidade de orientações. Você pode restaurar sua [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/585149/70) conforme as instruções passadas lá, e ao editar aquela postagem, ela será automaticamente destacada para que a comunidade reavalie via voto se está adequada ao objetivo do site.